# How to concatenate words from different files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a beginner in learning shell scripting in bash.

I have two different files:

Professionals.txt

```
ProID:ProName:CSLocal:n1:n2
```

```
12345:John Joe:CSBerlin:0:0
98765:Miller Key:CSMoscow:0:1
```

and

People.txt

```
peopleID:personName:Age:local:phone:n3
```

```
10001:Greg Linn:86:Berlin:912345678:0
10002:Peter Ronner:65:London:962345678:0
10003:Kelly Sena:91:Moscow:966645678:0
10004:Anne Tyler:87:Moscow:984973897:0
```

I need to do a script so I get an output file like:

output.txt

```
ProName:ProID:personName:personID:CSLocal
```

the `personName` will correspond to people who are in the same city as Professional

```
Miller Key:98765:Kelly Sena:10003:CSMoscow
Miller Key:98765:Anne Tyler:10004:CSMoscow
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
join -t: -1 3 -2 4 -o1.2,1.1,2.2,2.1,2.4 \
    <(sort -t: -k3,3 Professionals.txt ) \
    <(sort -t: -k4,4 People.txt | sed 's/^\(\([^:]*:\)\{3\}\)/\1CS/')
```

- **join** does exactly what you need: it matches two lists based on a given column. But it needs the lists to be sorted on the column, so that's what the rest of the code does.
- `-t` for both **sort** and **join** specify the column separator
- `-1` and `-2` tell **join** on which columns to join in the respective lists
- `-k` tells **sort** which column to sort on, `3,3` means "use only column 3"
- `-o` tells **join** what columns to output
- **sed** is used to add the `CS` prefix to cities in the People.txt list so the names match in the two lists

Comment: Damn! that's awesome, I didn't know about that command! But is there a way to do it with awk, sed , grep, sort, uniq? I was told that it with be too easy xD. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR { map[$4][$2]=$2":"$1;next } { for ( i in map[substr($3,3)] ) { print $2":"$1":"map[substr($3,3)][i]":"$3 } }' People.txt Professionals.txt
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR {                                                   # Process the first file (People.txt)
                  map[$4][$2]=$2":"$1;                               # Build a two dimensional array with the city as the first index and the name as the second. Have the name and the Id as the value
                  next 
                } 
                {                                                    # Process the second file
                  for ( i in map[substr($3,3)] ) { 
                    print $2":"$1":"map[substr($3,3)][i]":"$3        # Loop through the array where the first index is equal to the 3rd ":" separated field from the 3rd character onwards of the existing line, printing the data along with additional data from the existing line.
                  } 
                 }' People.txt Professionals.txt
```

Comment: what is map? is like a matrix?Why does map inside for just have 1 [ ]

Comment: map is a two dimensional array (two indexes) When looping, we are looping on the second index, hence only one []